# Execute fabric task from PyCharm

Tags: python, django, fabric, pycharm

I'm developing Django project in PyCharm and everything works properly. I've install fabric to my virtual env, and add fabfile.py in to my project. In this file I placed one test task definition:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello fabric!")
```

After that I'm trying to execute this task directly from my PyCharm. Do you have any suggestions  how can I do it?

Comment: I'm interested as well, for the time being I've just done some .cmd/.sh with the desired commands.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add a "Python" run configuration with `/path/to/your/env/bin/fab` as the script and `hello` as the script parameters.

Set the working directory to the directory with the fabfile.

Example:

[image]

Comment: now I get one more problem with executing fabric task from PyCharm. I've created separate question. If you have any advices I'll be thankful.

Comment: Is there any way of creating a Run Configuration that will ask for the value of "Script parameters" instead of creating a Run configuration for ever possible parameter?

Comment: Paidhi make a new fabric task that you call from PyCharm that stops to ask for those parameters and then calls the original task with the parameters it has received from the user.